# Postgres Join and return flag if a row exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very certain that this is possible in SQL but I am not sure how to implement this. I am using PostgreSQL

I have 2 tables

- `users` with columns id, name and created_date
- `user_docs` with columns id, value

I want to write a select query which returns all `users` table columns, along with another column called `has_docs` which indicates whether the user has any document rows in the `user_docs` table.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can left join the two tables and check if not null for the value

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.name,
       u.created_date,
       CASE WHEN ud.value IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END has_docs
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN user_docs ud
    ON u.id = ud.id
```

Comment: What if ud has a row but that value field is null? In this case wouldn't the query return wrong answer(it would say row doesn't exist but in fact row exists with value field being null)? Is value the primary key in this case?